# when connected and receive data from BLE device I get DOM exception: GATT server operation not permitted

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-lowenergy, arraybuffer, bluetooth-gatt, web-bluetooth

I am using web bluetooth api to connect with BLE 4.0 tractor trailer tester module using JavaScript. When connect I get in my console

Requesting any Bluetooth Device...
Connecting to GATT Server...
Getting Service...
Getting Characteristics... **then** DOM exception: GATT server operation not permitted
I don't know why this error pops. can anyone explain why is this?

```
async function onConnect() {

  try {

    console.log('Requesting any Bluetooth Device...');
    const device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
      acceptAllDevices: true
    });

    console.log('Connecting to GATT Server...');
    const server = await device.gatt.connect();

    console.log('Getting Service...');
    const service = await server.getPrimaryService('ef160001-ec80-4b4e-b481-b6c995777b5f');

    console.log('Getting Characteristics...');
    const characteristics = await service.getCharacteristics();

    for (const characteristic of characteristics) {
      switch (characteristic.uuid) { // characteristic.uuid

        case 'ef160003-ec80-4b4e-b481-b6c995777b5f': // receive
          await readValue1(characteristic);
          break;

        case 'ef160002-ec80-4b4e-b481-b6c995777b5f': // write
          await readAppearanceValue2(characteristic);
          break;

        case '00002a04-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb': // Manufacturer Name String
          await readValue3(characteristic);
          break;

        case '00002aa6-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb':
          await readValue4(characteristic); // Central Address Resolution
          break;

        default: console.log('Unknown Characteristic: ' + characteristic.uuid);
      }
    }

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }

  async function readValue1(characteristic) {

    const value = await characteristic.readValue();
    $('#dataset1').text(new TextDecoder().decode(value));
    console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(value));
  }

  async function readAppearanceValue2(characteristic) {

    const value = await characteristic.readValue();
    $('#dataset2').text(new TextDecoder().decode(value));
    console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(value));
  }

  async function readValue3(characteristic) {

    const value = await characteristic.readValue();
    $('#dataset3').text(new TextDecoder().decode(value));
    console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(value));
  }

  async function readValue4(characteristic) {

    const value = await characteristic.readValue();
    $('#dataset4').text(new TextDecoder().decode(value));
    console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(value));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're experiencing is not Web Bluetooth related, but a GATT Protocol error as described in the Bluetooth Core Specification (Version 5.0 Vol 3, Part F, 3.4.1.1)

I think those Bluetooth characteristics can't be read, hence why promises reject with this error which maps to "Read Not Permitted" in GATT world.
You may need to write some bytes to a dedicated characteristic so that the GATT server allows reading. I'd suggest reading software documentation if it exists, otherwise poking may help. In that case, have a look at `chrome://bluetooth-internals` to play with services/characteristics.

See https://web.dev/bluetooth/#tips as well for tips to debug Web Bluetooth.